# How does yelp and foursquare keeps the search icon in UISearchBar to the left in IOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar

In IOS 7 in UISearchBar, the search icon is to the center unless there is a text in the text bar.

In Yelp, the search icon is to the left. How do Yelp does it?

Answer (score 0):

Yelp build their own search bar view. It has two inputs and is not default iOS functionality and this is why it appears differently to the default UISearchBar.